# app.getElementById not working on html coming from HtmlService displayed in sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm working on embedding an intelligent tutor into a spreadsheet sidebar in Google Apps. We have our own javascript codebase that we already use to display things like math tutors on other websites like Moodle.

We just started exploring Google Apps and we are at the point where we have a project with a Code.gs, a Library.gs that contains all of our tutor Javascript code and an index.html. this index.html is very simple and looks something like:

```
<div id="container" name="container" class="container">Your browser does not support this tutor.</div>
```

It is this piece of html that is obtained using:

```
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setTitle('Tutor');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
```

From what I understand we can't use document.getElementById in our own js library. But when I do this in our Code.gs I do not get a reference to the canvas:

```
var canv=app.getElementById ("container");

Browser.msgBox (canv.innerHTML);
```

This does not display anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code.gs runs server side in google Apps Script. It can't access the html document that's running in your sidebar in your client browser. What are you hoping to do server-side with the contents of the container? You would normally use google.script.run.withFailureHandler() to send data from your sidebar to Google Apps Script and process it server side.